# How filter a dataframe in R using same condition between columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataset with 13 columns with theses names diag2-diag14. I need to filter using same criteria in this columns with 'or' as the logical operator.

```
diag2   diag3   diag4   diag5   diag6   diag7   diag8   diag9   diag10  diag11  diag12  diag13  diag14
E826.1                                              
813.42  924.8   E818.2  E849.5                                  
883.0   E819.9  E849.5                                      
821.01  805.05  813.42  802.0                       E819.9
```

My problem is, I don't wanna write 13 times same code like to look for my criteria (`'E818', 'E826'`) in each column...

ANYONE KNOWS A BETTER SOLUTION?

Thanks in advanced!
M

Comment: make an example dataset to get better replies.

Comment: so when any column in a row has E826 or E818, you want to return that row. Am I correct?

Comment: have you looked at the function any() in R for row operations? take a look at the documentations and see if you can figure it out. I have a meeting ill brb in 30 mins

Comment: Yeah Green Deamon, that's my question. I have and 'or' condition to check in 13 variables, so if one record passes a condition in one of these 13 variables I keep that record. I've coded this in SAS using macrolanguage but I need to do the same in R and I don't know how...

Comment: `?regex` with `?grepl` may help you out. You'll find there that there is an `|` operator you can use in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

- melt the dataframe with library reshape

or

- apply(df, 1, function(values){ any(values %in% criteria) })

Comment: I don't understand first option you mention. About second way, you mean something like this, do you?

function manu(diag2:diag14){
  any(diag2:diag14 %in% c('E810','E811','E812','E813','E814','E815','E816','E817','E818','E819','E826'))
}
prueba<-apply(cmbd_2010,1,manu(diag2:diag14))